# Executing two functions in the same onclick event but running one only once

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get an image to run two javascript functions at the same time, the problem is that I want the `changeImg()` function to run continually with each click but only execute the `clock()` function once. (So that it starts the timer).
`<img id="emotion" src="Target.jfif" width="50" onclick="changeImg();clock(); this.onclick=null;"/>`

This is my `changeImg()` script:

```
{
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*900);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*900);


var obj = document.getElementById("emotion");

obj.style.top = x + "px";
obj.style.left = y + "px";


 }
```

And this is my `clock()` script:

```
   function clock() {
     myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
     var c = 30;

     function myClock() {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = --c;
       if (c == 0) {
         clearInterval(myTimer);
         alert("Reached zero");
       }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have `clock()` check if the timer is already set, and return.

```
function clock() {
  if (myTimer) { // clock already started
    return;
  }
  myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
  var c = 30;

  function myClock() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = --c;
    if (c == 0) {
      clearInterval(myTimer);
      alert("Reached zero");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of passing `null` to onclick pass the function `changeImg`

```
onclick="changeImg();clock();this.onclick=changeImg;"
```

I don't know about good practices but it works without changing your code too much